# What's the difference between Favorites, Want to go, and Starred places?

Tags: google-maps

Does it make a difference where I save places?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are the three "core" lists that Google Maps supplies and I guess that theoretically they have different purposes.

The main difference is about the options available for each list, for example, the `Favorites` can't be hidden from your map, and the `Starred places` can't be shared.

**The available options:**

- **Favorites:**
  ❌ Hide 
  ✅ Share
- **Want to go**
  ✅ Hide 
  ✅ Share
- **Starred places**
  ✅ Hide 
  ❌ Share

The `edit` options is of course available for all lists, and the `delete` options is available only for user-created lists.

So it makes a difference where you save it only if the available options make difference to you for different scenarios.

Comment: I just tried and I actually could hide the favorites list on my map.

Comment: Maybe that's new, I'll have a look

Comment: There is a new one called _Travel Plans_. What's this one for?

Comment: @SaadMalik I'm also wandering what *Travel Plans* is for

Comment: 2023 Update - You can now Hide any of the lists. Starred is still Private and cannot be shared. So as far as I can tell, Favorites and Want to Go are simply normal lists that cannot be deleted, whereas Starred is a "personal" list.