# Moving bulk saved places in between labels in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have a lot of places saved in my Google Maps, which are currently saved under *Starred places* which is a list that [can't be shared](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/117480/177684).

Is there an easy way to move multiple saved places to another list so I could share them?

Answer (score -1):

Use Google Takeout to download the data. With KML format it can then be viewed in Maps by others.